# arc() not drawn in Processing 3

Tags: python, processing

I'm using Processing for Python to make a program to draw fractal wiggly lines, and the arc function doesn't appear to draw anything;

```
size(400,400)
noFill()
strokeCap(SQUARE)
import copy
roadcolour=(255,255,255)
edgecolour=(0,0,0)
roadwidth=10
edgewidth=1
coords=(100,100)
h=0

class Straight:

    def __init__(self,l):
        self.l=l

    def sketch(self):
        newcoords=(coords[0]+(cos(radians(h))*self.l),coords[1]+(sin(radians(h))*self.l))
        strokeWeight(roadwidth+edgewidth)
        stroke(*edgecolour)
        line(coords[0],coords[1],newcoords[0],newcoords[1])
        strokeWeight(roadwidth)
        stroke(*roadcolour)
        line(coords[0],coords[1],newcoords[0],newcoords[1])
        return newcoords,h

class Arc:

    def __init__(self,direction,degs,r):
        self.r=r
        self.dir=direction
        self.degs=degs

    def sketch(self):
        if self.dir=="R":
            centre=(coords[0]+(cos(radians(h+90))*self.r),coords[1]+(sin(radians(h+90))*self.r))
            starth=(h-90)%360
            endh=(starth+self.degs)%360
            newcoords=(centre[0]+(cos(radians(endh))*self.r),centre[1]+(sin(radians(endh))*self.r))
        else:
            centre=(coords[0]+(cos(radians(h-90))*self.r),coords[1]+(sin(radians(h-90))*self.r))
            endh=(h+90)%360
            starth=(endh-self.degs)%360
            newcoords=(centre[0]+(cos(radians(starth))*self.r),centre[1]+(sin(radians(starth))*self.r))
        centre=roundcoords(centre)
        newcoords=roundcoords(newcoords)
        print(centre,starth,endh,newcoords)
        strokeWeight(roadwidth+edgewidth)
        stroke(*edgecolour)
        arc(centre[0],centre[1],self.r*2,self.r*2,radians(starth),radians(endh))
        strokeWeight(roadwidth)
        stroke(*roadcolour)
        arc(centre[0],centre[1],self.r*2,self.r*2,radians(starth),radians(endh))
        return newcoords,h

def roundcoords(coords):
    return (int(coords[0]+0.5),int(coords[1]+0.5))

a=Arc('R',90,100)
a.sketch()
s=Straight(100)
s.sketch()
```

When I run this code, the straight line draws perfectly, with a black edge as desired, thus:

[image: the output]

and the program outputs `((100, 200), 270, 0, (200, 200))` as expected.

However, it doesn't draw any arc, as you can see; the program does not interrupt; the arcs are simply not drawn. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you must ensure that starth < endh, which isn't the case in your example.

Instead, you can draw one of those two arcs:

```
 arc(centre[0],centre[1],self.r*2,self.r*2,radians(endh),radians(starth))    
 arc(centre[0],centre[1],self.r*2,self.r*2,radians(starth),2*PI+radians(endh))
```

I hope it will solve your problem :)